# div not replcewith jquery function working on firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my JavaScript, I replace `div` tag with `li` start and end tags, but when I display the page in source code then it is showing me `<li></li>`.

Why does this happen? I want it as it is given in my `replaceWith` content

JavaScript part-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".separator").replaceWith("</li><li>");  
    });
</script>
```

HTML part-

```
<li>
    <img src="http://2012.sifasusa.com/images/kolorado-specs03.jpg" width="50%" height="500px" class="imgL zuper"/>
    <div class="caption captionH1" style="text-align: left;color: white;padding:10px;" dataeffects="fade top" dataoffset="30" datadelay="200" dataspeed="normal">
        Weather resistant
    </div>
    <div class="separator">
    </div>
    <img src="http://2012.sifasusa.com/images/kolorado-specs04.jpg" width="50%" height="500px" class="imgL zuper"/>
    <div class="caption captionH2" style="text-align: right;color: black;" dataeffects="fade right" dataoffset="30" datadelay="400" dataspeed="normal">
        White satin-finish methacrylate slats
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: I guess he's trying to replace `<div class="separator"></div>` with `</li><li>` so that it becomes 2 li's

Comment: I think he's trying to split the `<li>` into two, with the split happening where the `<div class="separator"></div>` is. Hence the closing tag before the opening one.

Comment: Yep, just realized that right before you commented

Comment: Your code seems to be working as a jsfiddle.  Maybe there's a problem with the way jquery is set up. http://jsfiddle.net/bozdoz/L3n4R/

Comment: ianpgall-this page i am working on both mobile and desktop version,but desktop version above code fine but in my mobile version i want to show only one image that's why i am separating the div tag with </li><li> to diff.another image tag

Comment: @ashwinpote can you hide the image in mobile with .hide()?

Comment: @bozdoz- hide the image is not require to me in my code

Answer (score 0):

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/KLkJ3/2/

---

You'll probably need to do something like:

```
$('.seperator').each(function() {

    // create a new LI
    // move everything after .seperator to the new LI
    // insert new LI after the current LI
    $('<li/>').append($(this).nextAll()).insertAfter($(this).parent());

    // remove the sperator
    $(this).remove();

});
```

Comment: @K.K please see this problem and tell me if u have any suggestions

Comment: I've added a demo. Pls check.

Comment: but i don't want on this any click event

Comment: I put it in a click event just for the demo. You can use that code inside your ready() event for your requirement. I'll update the fiddle.

Comment: it's working fine in desktop version but not working on mobile version